# What is the meaning of 'git' in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I watched a movie about some cowboys and Indians in Texas, but needed to pause, when one of the cowboys put his hands on his belt and shouted "Git" at the person coming towards him.

What does "Git" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'Git' means to *move along*, *start walking*, *vamoose*.**

["Git Along, Little Dogies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_Along,_Little_Dogies) is a traditional cowboy ballad documented before the turn of the century, and popularized by movie westerns and recordings. In the song, "git along" is a command to keep moving. The "little dogies" are cattle being herded to market.

The origin may be a [vocal command for horse training](http://petcaretips.net/horse-training-voice-commands.html). I was not able to find a specific reference to *git*, but it fits the pattern of monosyllable commands like *woah* for 'stop' and *hup* for 'back up'. *Git* is similar to another cowboy horse command [giddyup](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddyap) meaning 'go fast'.

A later tongue-in-cheek phrase [git to gittin'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHFIny_ZVP4) means *hurry up and start*.

Answer (score 3):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/git)

> **git**
>   dialectal variant of GET

That means it is a variation of the word "get" based on the pronunciation in the dialect of the Old West.

So it means the same as yelling "Get!", meaning "Go!" or "Go away!"